# multi threads for sending emails

Tags: c#, multithreading, smtp, threadpool, sendmail

I have a listview with the names of the email lists (on import it is adding the path and the name).
I have another listview with smtp servers with 5 columns: ip, port, user, pass, type (normal, ssl, tls)
a backgroundworker for progress bar purposes.

```
int cnt = this.listView1.CheckedItems.Count;//email lists
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                startsend();
            }
```

so for each list of emails in the listView1 it will do the function.

but I don't know how to make the function to use 20-30 threads and also use all the smtp servers(not random) I have in listView2 (checkeditems) to send the emails. 
I have only 3 smtp servers but I still wanna use 20 threads.

I tried to find a solution to this for more than a week but I couldn't. I saw that here are many experts and maybe you can help a n00b user.

**How can I send the emails from each listView1.CheckedItems using smtp servers which are rotated from listView2.CheckedItems and also using 20-30 threads ?**
Thank you!

Comment: Voting to close: while question itself looks reasonable, valid answers most likely need to explain how to mass-send e-mails. Please consider splitting your question into chunks that can be answered in more generic way (i.e. "how to randomly pick one string out of 3" instead of "need to chose random SMTP server").

Comment: Seems to me you want to use a bulk email service such as ActiveTrail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should use `foreach` for this task, it's much more readable. So first you can iterate over the servers, then over the email lists and in the inner loop send mails in parallel:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(20, 20);
int activeWorkers = 0;
object signal = new object();

foreach(/* server in listView2 */)
{
    foreach(/* email in listView1 */)
    {
        lock(signal) ++activeWorkers; // keep track of active workers

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            o =>
            {
                string email = (string)o;
                startsend(server, email);                   

                lock(signal) // signal termination
                {
                   --activeWorkers;
                   Monitor.Pulse(signal);                    
                }
            }, email);

        lock(signal) 
        {
           while(activeWorkers > 0) // improvised barrier
               Monitor.Wait(signal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I will test this and hope I will be able to implement your idea.

Comment: I added your function and I get the following error: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listView2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. Can you help me out?

Comment: no, I modified your code with this: foreach (ListViewItem smtp in listView2.CheckedItems) { foreach (string email in GLOBAL_EMAILS)
                    { your code } }

Comment: Did you put this code inside another thread? Or is it executed on the GUI thread?

Comment: no, it is executed directly, but I added a line to write each email processed to a textbox. can it be from there?

Comment: @Sam Reina: Yes. You cannot update the GUI controls from other threads. Are you using WPF or winforms?

Comment: I'm using winforms and I'm trying to send the email processed to a log windows which in this case is a textbox. I don't know if this is the best solution but since I'm new to c# I don't know another one.

Comment: Ok, so in order to update a control from a different thread you have to use `Control.BeginInvoke` to forward the update to the GUI thread. You have to wrap your code inside a delegate and pass it to `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: there is no button to accept your answer. How can I accept it ?

Comment: There is a tick on the left side below the score of the answer. :)

Comment: btw, your code works just great and I'm so sorry I don't have 15 rep to vote for you. Anyway thanks for your help and if you feel in a good mood to help me again, I have another issue. question no: 10362406